# Explorer attribute doesn't zoom in Google Charts with Angular 9

Tags: angular, google-visualization

I'm displaying a Google Line Chart and everything is working properly, but now I want to zoom the graph and I have seen that this is available to do it with the property called `explorer` in the `options` object that is injected to the google line chart component. I got this:

```
options = {
    curveType: 'function',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    explorer : {
        actions: ['dragToZoom'],
        axis: 'horizontal',
        keepInBounds: true,
        maxZoomIn: 4.0
    },
    legend: { position: 'right' }
};
```

An this is what I'm injecting to the component;

```
<google-chart style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" #chart *ngIf="!loading"
              [type]="'LineChart'"
              [columnNames]="columnNames"
              [data]="data"
              [width]="1200"
              [height]="900"
              [options]="options">
</google-chart>
```

This is how the `data` variable looks like:

```
data = [ 
    { 0: "Wed May 31 2006"
      1: 24.962499618530273
      2: 24.962499618530273 },
    { 0: "Thu Jun 01 2006"
      1: 25.0
      2: 25.1 },
      ...
```

But when I try to zoom the graph with the mouse wheel it doesn't work... what am I doing wrong with this?

Comment: the explorer option is only supported by a continuous axis --> number, date, datetime, timeofday, etc... -- data shown above is using a string, which produces a discrete axis...

Comment: Wow that's why it doesn't work! Solve it without using the Date as a string @WhiteHat